# Runtime discrete nonlinear dynamical system

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

I consider a discrete non-linear dynamical system.
I know it is asymptotically stable because all eigenvalues evaluated at the fix point have modulus less than one.

Now I am interested in the runtime.

Are the any techniques to obtain the runtime?
Is the runtime related to the largest eigenvalue at the fix point?

By runtime I mean the number of iterations needed until being close to the optimal solution. 
I currently do not know how to quantify "close to an optimal solution", I am just interested if there are results known.

Comment: What do you understand as "being close"? You can compute with the largest eigenvalue how many iterations it takes maximally to reduce the distance to the fixed point by a factor of $10$.

Comment: Yes, I am not sure how to define being close. Something like "in distance $\varepsilon$". How does it work with the largest eigenvalue and the factor of 10?

Comment: As usual with a geometric sequence as upper bound. Name $\rho$ the radius of the set of eigenvalues, then $d(x_n,x_*)\le \rho^n\,d(x_0,x_*)$, and to compute $n$ you need to apply the logarithm to this inequality. If you want to bound the absolute error, you also need an estimate of the initial distance. Practically, you could try to estimate them via linear regression on the table $n\mapsto \log(d(x_{n+1},x_n)\simeq n\log(\rho)+\log(d(x_1,x_0))$.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thank you. Is it also possible to derive a lower bound in a similar way?

Comment: You can use the radius of the smallest eigenvalue of the Jacobian at the fixed point to get such approximate lower bounds. This assumes that you already know the fixed point, making the whole exercise somewhat futile. In general, lower bounds for distances are a bit more complicated, as the triangle inequality lends itself more naturally towards upper bounds.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question: do you know a book or article, etc. that explains the first approach (it looks quite simple but I need a source).